# Estimating parameters for shifted Poisson distribution

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-distribution, fitting

Suppose I have a data vector `v`, in which all values are greater than zero.

Now, I want to see if it follows a shifted Poisson distribution.

Can I do it by shifting everything to the left first, and fitting a Poisson in the usual fashion? For example, in R I can fit a Poisson by using the "`fitdistr`" function. Can I do `vec <- v - 1` to shift everything to the left first (so that we can treat it like normal Poisson distribution)? And then run `fitdistr(vec, "poisson")`.

Second Question: 
Now suppose I want to carry out a `chisq.test()`. The frequency table of the actual data vector `vec`is as follow:

```
table(vec)
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   16   17   18   19   20   21   22 
 611 1297 1893 2730 2759 2198 1525  927  456  243   75   39   18    7    2    1    2    4   12   20   34   34 
  23   24   25   26   27   30   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   47   48   52   54   55 
  19   13    8    2    1    3    1    4    7    7   10    8    5    2    8    3    3    3    1    1    1    2 
  56   57   58   67   70   71   75  188 
   2    1    3    1    1    1    1    1
```

And to construct chi-squared goodness of fit test, I did:

```
p1 <- dpois(0:188, lambda = 4.33657562) 
p1 <- c(p1, 1 - sum(p1))
names(p1) <- c(0:188, "more")
chisq.test(table(factor(vec, levels = c(0:188, "more") )), p = p1)
```

I do not know why I got p value = `NA` at the end. Please explain to me what is going wrong here ?

`X-squared = NaN, df = 189, p-value = NA`

The distribution of discrete data is as follows, with the purple line  - the shifted poisson distribution ($\lambda = 4.33$)

Comment: Suddenly, this looks very familiar. Is this for some class?

Comment: No, but I am preparing myself for class in future

Comment: Then it would appear to count as `self-study`, but perhaps it's not absolutely critical here.

Comment: I have been stuck in this p value = `NA` problem for almost the whole day. I just wanted to know what went wrong. It would be helpful, if you can give me some help in this problem, because I think I am still not grasping the concept of chisq test well enough.

Comment: Try working out the contribution to chi-square of the last cell by hand. That would be my guess as to why you get NA. Incidentally, I think the occurrence of a value of 188 with that sample size rules out a Poisson(4.33) pretty comprehensively.

Comment: So it is because of dividing by zero, which gives `NaN` ?

Comment: Well, I imagine that would be enough for it to avoid trying to compute a p-value (a sensible routine would return a missing p-value for that case). You could check the code for the test, I guess, but it's pretty obvious that's why it can't. The actual value is bigger than 0 of course.

Comment: it (the total probability for the rest of the table) is about 1.0235 times as big as the value at 188.

Comment: Sorry, that's including 188. Correction: everything past 188 should have about 0.0235 times the value of the probability at 188 (assuming that's at all accurate, which it may not be). You shouldn't use the chi-square approximation going out this far, by the way. Simulate, if you can afford the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that strategy - shifting back, then estimating in the usual way - should work fine (with the proviso that you then need to shift the resulting fitted distribution back again if you want to write it as a shifted Poisson on the original data).

An example in R, using `fitdistr`:

```
 v <- rpois(110,3.2)+1  # make up some data
 library(MASS)
 vfit <- fitdistr(v-1,"poisson")
 vfit
    lambda  
  3.1909091 
 (0.1703181)
 obf <- as.vector(table(v)/sum(table(v)))
 plot(1:8,obf,type="h",lwd=2,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,0.25))
 lines((1:10)+.05,dpois(0:9,3.191),col=2,type="h",lwd=2)
 abline(h=0,col=8)
```

[image: shifted Poisson, observed and fitted]

Comment: Thanks. Actually, there is one more question I want to ask. Please see edited question in 30 minutes.

Comment: I hope the discussion in comments under the question is now sufficient to cover that issue for you.